# aligning columns in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following bootstrap layout ([with a bootply](https://www.bootply.com/BcK28CTKul)).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
      <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>64</p></div></item>
      <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>128</p></div></item>
      <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>256</p></div></item>
      <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>512</p></div></item>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
      <item class="col-9"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
    </div>
</div>
```

It produces the following:

[image]

Is it at all possible to re-arrange the html to produce this?

[image]

and for it to remain responsive (the last green 32 can just take up as much space as it can until it has to wrap - which is the default behaviour)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
  <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>64</p></div></item>
  <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>128</p></div></item>
  <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>256</p></div></item>
  <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>512</p></div></item>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <item class="col" style="max-width: 20%"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
  <item class="col"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
</div>
```

This seems to give what you need!

Answer (score 0):

Would this be responsive enough?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <item class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
      <item class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><div class="card-block"><p>64</p></div></item>
      <item class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><div class="card-block"><p>128</p></div></item>
      <item class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><div class="card-block"><p>256</p></div></item>
      <item class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><div class="card-block"><p>512</p></div></item>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <item class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
      <item class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"><div class="card-block"><p>32</p></div></item>
  </div>
</div>
```